# update attribute for rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I'm trying to make admin user can edit one attribute of a "post"

The post model is:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :admin_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post][:some_attr])
     flash[:success] = "Post updated"
     redirect_to posts_path
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

The edit view is :

```
  <% provide(:title, "Edit post") %> 
  <h1>Update the post</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :some_attr %>
        <%= f.text_field :some_attr %>

    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
```

When I try to input "123" in the some_attr test_field in edit page, it renders error:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#update

undefined method `stringify_keys' for "123":String


Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:22:in `update'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"EdTg+cFBnZY447oSDqSTPfb/PJ6VisJOrQ8kvichDrE=",
 "post"=>{"some_attr"=>"123"},
 "commit"=>"Save changes",
 "id"=>"17"}
```

What could be the problem? Which piece of the puzzle am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
 if @post.update_attributes(params[:post][:some_attr])
```

`params[:post][:some_attr]` is just a value. A field is not specified. If you change the line to

```
 if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
```

the attribute should update as expected.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem! Actually update_attributes is expecting a hash instead of a string

Comment: Yep, exactly. You can pass in an entire hash of attributes to update. [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes) is some documentation on `update_attributes` if you're curious.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this line:

```
@post.update_attributes(params[:post][:some_attr])
```

should read like this:

```
@post.update_attributes(params[:post])
```

To perform an update to `@post`, you need to pass in the entire hash of attributes for it -- not just the one you're changing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That's right..I should do more researching before ask